# while read loop ignoring last line in file

Tags: bash

Reading in a file , `members_08_14.csv` which just contains a list of numbers, the while loop is reading each line. For each line, the number is matched against a regex to ensure that it's only numbers and exactly 11 characters long.

```
while read card
do
    if [[ $card =~ ^[0-9]{11}$ ]]
    then
        echo "some sql statement with $card" >> temp.sql;
    else
        echo "Invalid card number in file: $card";
    fi
done <registered/members_08_14.csv
```

The interesting thing is, the else is not being executed if the regex does not match. I would expect that either the line would be written to `temp.sql`, or a line would be printed to `stdout` saying the card number is invalid.

The behaviour, however, is more along the lines of either only the `true` condition or only the `false` condition gets activated for the entire file. Why would this be?

Here's the contents of registered/members_08_14.csv:

```
47678009583
47678009585
47678009587
47678009590
476780095905
```

The first lines are valid, the 5th line is invalid.

Output of `cat -vte registered/members_08_14.csv`

```
47678009583$
47678009585$
47678009587$
47678009590$
476780095905$
```

Comment: I have no idea, but it works great on my computer.

Comment: When I run that code, I get `Invalid card number in file: 476780095905`

Comment: Maybe the last line of your file is missing a trailing newline? If that's the case, `read` will fail and the entire loop iteration won't run.

Comment: Well, it works perfectly fine on my bash 4.3-1 on Debian unstable...

Comment: Show output of `cat -vte registered/members_08_14.csv` in your question.

Comment: What does `set -x` give you for the iteration with the line in question?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I believe you were correct with a trailing newline. When I added the newline to the end of the file (and then removed it again) it seemed to work. The file did originally come from a Windows machine.

Comment: I took the liberty of updating the summary to better reflect the actual problem, in the hope that this helps other folks in the same boat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the last line of your file has no newline on the end, `read` will put its content into  `card` -- but will then exit with a nonzero value. Because `read` has exited with a nonzero value in this case, the `while` loop will exit without going on to the statement that runs the regex at all.

The easiest fix is to correct the file.

Another approach you can take is to ignore the exit status of `read` when it actually populates its destination (and, while at it, to put `$'\r'` into IFS, such that `read` will ignore the extra characters in DOS newlines):

```
while card=; IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -r card || [[ $card ]]; do
    if [[ $card =~ ^[0-9]{11}$ ]]
    then
        echo "some sql statement with $card" >> temp.sql;
    else
        echo "Invalid card number in file: $card";
    fi
done <registered/members_08_14.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your file is in DOS format that you also get to read carriage returns (`\r`) to the end of the variable. Try to run `dos2unix file` or `sed -i 's|\r||' file`. Another way is to trim out that character after every input through this

```
while IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -r card
```

Comment: If the file were in DOS format, wouldn't _every_ line go through the `else` case?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm just guessing. He was not specific which parts of the lines were getting the proper condition or not.

Comment: I believe this was it. The file originally came from Windows, and when I added a new line to the end of the file (and then removed it again) it seemed to have worked.

Comment: @Hypino: But `cat -vte` isn't showing presence of `^M` in each line.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry for the confusion, the `cat -vte` was from after I made a change as per @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 0):

To read all the lines, regardless of whether they are ended with a new line or not:

```
cat "somefile" | { cat ; echo ; } | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

Source : My open source project https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/

Comment: You could of course use `{ cat "somefile"; echo; } | ...` and make the pipeline that much shorter. Or `cat "somefile" <(echo) | ...`